# Does Python Timer have some limitation for supported longest time?

Tags: python, timer

```
import threading
import os

def shutdown():
    os.system("shutdown -s")

# user setting zone!!!
hour = 0
minute = 20
sec = 0
# user setting zone!!!

total_sec = hour*3600.0 + minute*60.0 + sec - 60.0

if total_sec < 0:
    total_sec = 0
print("The computer will be Shut Down in (%d hour, %d minute, %d second).\n" %(hour, minute, sec))

if total_sec >= 120:
    temp_sec = total_sec - 120
    threading.Timer(temp_sec, lambda: print("Last 3 minutes before shuting down the computer!!\n")).start()
else:
    print("Less than 3 minutes before shuting down the computer!!\n")

threading.Timer(total_sec, shutdown).start()
```

The code is shown above. When I set a short time like 10 min, 20 min or a little longer, the script could work normally. But if I set the waiting time to a long time like 4 hours or 5 hours, the script could NOT work at all. Nothing would happen when the time is up. Could you pls point out why the error happens and guide me to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could be wrong, but don't you need a loop in there somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I did't get the meaning of the loop that you mentioned. Could you pls give some example?

Comment: Nevermind, seems it isn't needed, although it does show where you're probably off.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually timed it? You say it works normally, but does it actually shut the computer off in 10 minutes when set for 10 minutes, and not say 15+ minutes?

I ask because it looks like you have it set to give you a 3 minute warning. However then the timer resets because you use total_sec in "threading.Timer(total_sec, shutdown).start()" So when you set it for say 60 minutes, it gives you a warning at 57 minutes, then runs for another 60 minutes.

Therefore, I suspect if you let it run for 11 hours, when you set it for 5 hours, it would actually shutoff the computer.

Comment: I just did a test for 5 min from 11:49, and the 3-min warning showed at 11:51, and the "shutdown" command was executed at 11:53 (one minute in advance cause Windows "shutdown" command takes 1 min to show system warning before shutting down the computer). So it looked like working normally for short time...

Comment: So it seems I probably should have looked at the documentation before commenting. I'm thinking you're probably right in that there's a timeout somewhere. Although not sure where it is.

Comment: Never mind. Thanks for your answers all the same :)  The official document for Python should really have remarked the possible timeout problem (if we were right...) about Timer but they haven't...